# Get Post ID from URL in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, url, post

I need a help about I want to get the post ID from URL as I have send using

```
?id='1'
```

I want to get that ID and fetch that data on another WordPress page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> To get the value from `GET` parameter you can use
>   [`filter_input()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-input.php), or WordPress [`get_query_var()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_query_var) method. And
>   after getting the ID you can query post by using [`WP_Query`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query).

```
$post_id = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'id');
if (!empty($post_id))
{
    $args = [
        'post_type' => 'bcworks', //<--replace it with your post_type
        'p' => $post_id
    ];
    // The Query
    $the_query = new WP_Query($args);
}
else
{
    //no post found
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: How will i get the post title and content from $the_query

Comment: Can you please help me on filter search like name, address and zip code form search

Comment: Actually, only one question post for oneday. That's why I'm asking

Comment: @NoorAlam: pls read this https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4359/is-there-a-limit-on-how-many-questions-i-can-ask

Comment: OK. I have added a question

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/295172/custom-name-location-zipcode-search

Answer (score 0):

To fetch data on another WordPress with id use below code

```
<?php

// would echo post 7's content up until the <!--more--> tag
$post_7 = get_post(7); 
$excerpt = $post_7->post_excerpt;
echo $excerpt

// would get post 12's entire content after which you
// can manipulate it with your own trimming preferences
$post_12 = get_post(12); 
$trim_me = $post_12->post_content;
my_trim_function( $trim_me );

?>
```